# Netlify: How to create domain alias dynamically on Netlify

Tags: subdomain, netlify

currently in Netlify you can create aliases of my custom domain normally, but I would like to know if i can add these alias from an API / Programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

Netlify provides documentation on their [api](https://www.netlify.com/docs/api/#sites) including the following:

> #### UPDATE SITE
>
> `PATCH /api/v1/sites/{site_id}` will let you update some attributes on a site
>   `PUT /api/v1/sites/{site_id}` will let you update some attributes on a site
>
> This lets you update a site. Takes all the same parameters as when
>   creating a site.
>
> When creating a site, you can set the following properties:
>
> `name`, the name of the site (mysite.netlify.com)
>   `custom_domain`, the custom domain of the site (www.example.com)
>   `password`, password protect the site
>   `force_ssl`, will force SSL on the site if SSL is enabled
>   `domain_aliases`, is an array of OTHER hostnames your site has in addition to the custom domain
>   `processing_settings`, lets you set the following processing settings: `{“css”: {“bundle”: true, “minify”: true}, “js”: {“bundle”: true, “minify”: true}, “html”: {“pretty_urls”: true, “canonical_urls”: true}, “images”: {“optimize”: true}}`
>   `repo`, lets you configure continuous deployment. It’s a bit complicated to create a repo object so please contact support for guidance if you want to do this.

Based on this, I suspect you would be able to use their API to adjust your custom domain - however they do not make any reference to a means to adjust aliases such that you can control more than one domain at a time. You may be able to contact their support team and request assistance if that is something you require.

Comment: The Netlify support team has been an amazing help to me when I was getting my custom domains setup, and they usually respond within a few hours which, considering the service is free, is as awesome as their help. That being said, I can confirm what Ben said in that I don't recall ever seeing an option to handle domain aliases dynamically.

Comment: I work for Netlify support and that is indeed the only way to dynamically update a DNS record *using Netlify's DNS hosting*.  Of course you can use any DNS host including ones that have dynamic dns support and still host your sites on our CDN!